# Can custom HTTP error 500 be specified under Location directive?

Tags: apache, weblogic, errordocument

and sorry in advance I'm a newbie in HTTP server.

I'd like to customize an error 500 from an Oracle HTTP Server (OHS, built on Apache). I guess this should be done from the `ErrorDocument` directive, but I never found any example where this is used to customize Webspace error, only Filesystem one (under `Directory` or `File` directives).

To be more precise, here is a part of the default config used:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/analytics$ /analytics/

## Context roots for BI EE
<Location /analytics >
 SetHandler weblogic-handler
 WebLogicCluster miaibv194.mia.michelin.com:9704
</Location>
```

If I understand well, the `RedirectMatch` and `Location` directives are used to pass URLs like /analytics to Weblogic. Is it possible to add an `ErrorDocument` under the `Location` to customize errors 500 that occur for URLs like /analytics ?

I tried naively but could not make it work. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I was originally trying to achieve was to customize HTTP errors 500 in OBIEE 11g (which uses WebLogic, and an OHS in our case). I opened a SR to try to achieve that with OHS, but it failed (Oracle guy told me I had to do it at application level), so I opened a new one to do it with WebLogic itself and here is what it gives:

• Locate the analytics.ear in your Oracle BI Home directory. This will be /Oracle_BI1 (or whatever you chose to name your Oracle BI Home on install)/bifoundation/analytics.ear.
So in our example scenario, this would be located at:
C:\OBI\Oracle_BI1\bifoundation\jee\analytics.ear
• Make a backup copy of the ear file so that you have a restore point to refer back to (and revert to) if needed
Note that we do not support updating the analytics.ear file, you must stop, remove the previous analytics.ear file before deploying the new one.

• Unpack the analytics.ear file to a temporary location, using the Java jar tool. Use the command line options xvf to extract the contents
to the current working directory (e.g. C:\OBI\jdk160\bin\jar –xvf C:\OBI\Oracle_BI1\bifoundation\jee\analytics.ear), so you will probably want to create a
temporary directory to hold the unpacked contents and change into that directory before running the command.

The ear contains a META-INF directory and two war files, analytics.war and analytics-ws.war

• In the META-INF directory, there is a MANIFEST.MF file, add the following line to the end of the file:
Weblogic-Application-Version: 11.1.1
Note that it has been reported that when re-applying these steps following the application of BI 11.1.1.5.0 BP2 patches, this step to update MANIFEST.MF should be ignored as the new analytics.ear file is not versioned.

• Unpack the analytics.war file to a second temporary location; it contains a default.jsp file and five top-level directories, one of which is called WEB-INF.

• in the WEB-INF directory, you will find an existing file called web.xml. Edit web.xml, for example by adding:

```
<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/500error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Make sure there are no hidden characters and check the quotes are correct for your platform.

• Once you have edited the web.xml , repackage the analytics.war file, again using the jar tool, and, in turn, repackage that back into the analytics.ear file.
Next we need to redeploy the analytics.ear file to Weblogic

• Log into Weblogic Admin Console and click on Deployments

• In the Change Centre at the top left, click “Lock and Edit”

• Find the analytics app and click the tickbox next to it, then click on the Update button

• In the Update Application Assistant screen, make sure the deployment path is the same as the ear file you just updated, if not change the path

• Click Next, then Finish

• In the Change Centre at the top left, click “Activate Changes” to save your changes. If you have not already done so, restart the Weblogic Admin Server and all Managed Servers